# Why won't my flex-item input and buttons fit the parent container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I was learning Flex the other day and tried to make a reusable cart component – with a text input and two button controls on both sides of it.

I want it to be flexible. Meaning wherever I put this component it will fill 100% width of its parent container. This doesn't work though as you can see in the snippet.

Can somebody please explain why and how to fix this? Thank you so much.

```css
.component {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 35px;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.component button {
  border: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #ddd;
  min-width: 35px;
}

.component input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background: #ccc;
}

main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>Simply not enough space…</p>

<main style="max-width: 150px">
  <div class="component">
    <button type="button">&laquo;</button>
    <input placeholder="Type quantity">
    <button type="button">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
</main>

<p>Here it still doesn't fit…</p>

<main style="max-width: 200px">
  <div class="component">
    <button type="button">&laquo;</button>
    <input placeholder="Type quantity">
    <button type="button">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
</main>

<p>Here it has enough space so it fits…</p>

<main style="max-width: 300px">
  <div class="component">
    <button type="button">&laquo;</button>
    <input placeholder="Type quantity">
    <button type="button">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: min-width: 0; to input

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nope; `input` HTML property `size` overrules CSS property of `min-width` or `width`.

Comment: Well, his suggestion seams to work actually.

Comment: @TylerH nope :) this is a flexbox issue related to the default min-width applied to elements that you need to override using min-width:0

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif. In gratitude I'll upvote your other answers.

Comment: @TemaniAfif looks like *both* approaches work here :-)

Comment: no don't do it, the system wil revert all your upvotes and will block any legit upvotes :/ .. this will hurt more than it will help ..

Comment: So I've upvoted one ;) Thanks again.